# Why is my JulianDay returning null when trying to get number of days between two dates

Tags: sqlite, datetime, julian-date

Hi I am trying to get the number of days between two dates in one of my tables `arrivaldate` and `departuredate` however i dont know why my JulianDay is returning null value.

```
Select Cast ((
JulianDay(datetime(departuredate)) - JulianDay(datetime(arrivaldate))) As Integer) 
from booking;
```

My table

```
CREATE table Booking(
  BookingID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, 
  BCustomerID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  arrivaldate VARCHAR(10) NULL, 
  departuredate VARCHAR(10) NULL, 
  paymentmethod VARCHAR (45)NULL, 
  RoomType VARCHAR (20)
);

INSERT INTO Booking(BCustomerID,arrivaldate,departuredate,paymentmethod,RoomType) VALUES 
(1,'2018/07/02','2018-07-10','Card','Single'), 
(2,'2018/07/12','2018-07-18','Cash','Double'), 
(3,'2018/07/12','2018-07-19','Cash','Single'), 
(4,'2018/07/06','2018-07-07','Card','Double'), 
(5,'2018/08/14','2018-08-24','Card','Triple'), 
(6,'2018/09/01','2018-09-04','Cash', 'Quad');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite's datetime functions like `datetime()` and `julianday()` work only for dates in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or datetimes in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sss'`.
Your dates contain `'/'` instead of `'-'` (only in `arrivaldate` or `departuredate` too?).
Use the function `replace()`:

```
SELECT CAST (
         julianDay(REPLACE(departuredate, '/', '-')) - 
         julianDay(REPLACE(arrivaldate, '/', '-'))
         AS integer
       ) AS days
FROM booking;
```

Or better update the table so your dates have the proper for SQLite format:

```
UPDATE booking
SET arrivaldate = REPLACE(arrivaldate, '/', '-'),
    departuredate= REPLACE(departuredate, '/', '-')
```

and then you can do:

```
SELECT CAST(julianDay(departuredate) - julianDay(arrivaldate) AS integer) AS days
FROM booking;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d509328c6894040093df303c2cf4fd55).

Comment: Thank you so much I just remembered that I changed the format of one of them for my project